# Connection Error between MS Access and IPython with pyodbc

Tags: python-2.7, ms-access, anaconda, pyodbc

when I run my script see below i got the follwing error.

```js
import pyodbc

cnxn = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};UID=admin;UserCommitSync=Yes#;Threads=3;SafeTransactions=0;PageTimeout=5;MaxScanRows=8;MaxBufferSize=2048;FIL={MS Access};DriverId=25;DefaultDir=C:\Users\XXX;DBQ=C:\Users\XXX\Database.mdb")

cursor = cnxn.cursor()

cursor.execute("SELECT Monat FROM TW-DS")

row = cursor.fetchone()
if row:
    print(row)
```

I have a windows 7 professional version in 64-Bit and run on anaconda 32-Bit with python 2.7.12.
My MS-Access is a 32-Bit-Version and I use the 32-Bit OBDC connection generator from windowns for my path generation.

i got this error message:

```html
ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntaxfehler in FROM-Klausel. (-3506) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

Could anybody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a SQL Server foible - it doesn't like hyphens. Try this:

```
SELECT Monat FROM [TW-DS]
```

That'll allow you to use hyphens in your table or database names.

Comment: Can you mark the answer correct by clicking the check mark?